# Clarification about the Antiderivative of $x^{-1/3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In some textbook the antiderivative of $x^{-1/3}$ is written as 
$$\int x^{-1/3}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}+C,$$ where $C$ is a constant. But should not the following function also be considered as an antiderivative of $x^{-1/3}$?

$$
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}+C_0,\text{ if $x$>0}\\
\frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}+C_1,\text{ if $x$<0}
\end{cases}
$$

When $C_0\neq C_1$, F(x) cannot be written as $\frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}+C$.

**Edit**: I would like to clarify: which one of the following should be the correct answer to $\int x^{-1/3}\mathrm{d}x$:

- $\frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}+C$,
- or $
  \begin{cases}
  \frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}+C_0,\text{ if $x$>0}\\
  \frac{3}{2}x^{2/3}+C_1,\text{ if $x$<0}
  \end{cases}?
  $

Comment: Usually, an antiderivative is defined on an interval.

Comment: C is just an arbitrary constant , so i think it has no effect on the function you obtain (unless given previous constraints), since both $C_0$ and$ C_1$ vanish when differentiated. I dont know if thats the right answer you're looking for tho.

Comment: How do you know they are different constants?

Comment: @AndrewLi, my question is, should I use two constants in my answer, or should I use only one constant? My guess is that two is correct, though I seldom see it is written this way.

Comment: @Zuriel Can you show me an example where $C_0 \neq C_1$?

Comment: @AndrewLi, take $C_0=0$ and $C_1=1$; you still have $F'(x)=x^{-1/3}$.

Comment: The first question is, which values $x$ can take at $f(x)$? This you have to clarify first. The $\texttt{domain}$ is part of a function.

Comment: @Zuriel But $3/2(x^{2/3}) + 1$ is a whole different function than $3/2(x^{2/3})$, not just in positive in negative cases... that's precisely why we just write $C$? What example do you have present a function that has different $C$ values depending on the sign?

Comment: @callculus, I would define the domain as $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\neq 0\}$.

Comment: @AndrewLi, I was just wondering if we need to use two constants in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand $x^{-1/3}$ has a singularity at $x=0$ and you cannot integrate across it. So the expressions in the negatives and in the positives are independent of each other and you can very well consider two constants. The derivative of the antiderivative and the original function do match wherever the function is defined.

In practice it is often the case that you integrate in a single interval, so that the existence of another branch doesn't matter and writing $C$ (which disappears in the definite integral) is enough.

---

This generalizes to functions with more singularities, say

$$2\int\frac{dx}{x^2-1}=\begin{cases}
x<-1&\to\log\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|+C_0,\\
-1<x<1&\to\log\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|+C_1,\\
x>1&\to\log\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|+C_2.\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: the singularity is integrable

Comment: @thedude: that doesn't change the answer. The derivatives on both sides are correct and the change of the constant cannot create a discontinuity.

Comment: You write "The integrand $x^{−1/3}$ has a singularity at $x=0$ and you cannot integrate across it". Why not?

Comment: @thedude Because it is improper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does it mean that we cannot integrate $x^{-1/3}$ on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Zuriel: yes you can, keeping in mind the discontinuity.